# space before and after enumerate in a longtable, when hyperref was applied

Tags: spacing, hyperref, longtable, enumerate

I am quite confused about how to remove the space before and after the items within `enumerate` within the cell of `longtable`.

The tex code is listed below:

```
\begin{longtable}{>{\centering}p{108pt}@{\hspace{7pt}}>{}p{375pt}}
\textcolor{lightgray}{factors} & \textcolor{darkgray}{
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,topsep=-1em,parsep=0pt]    
\item  a
\item  b       
\item  c  
\item  d       
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{longtable}
```

The two cells cannot be top aligned, unless I put some words before `enumerate`.

```
\begin{longtable}{>{\centering}p{108pt}@{\hspace{7pt}}>{}p{375pt}}
\textcolor{lightgray}{factors} & \textcolor{darkgray}{
Some words here
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,topsep=-1em,parsep=0pt]    
\item  a
\item  b       
\item  c  
\item  d       
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{longtable}
```

The question is how to realize this without using `vspace` before `enumerate`?

#######UPDATE

I happened to find that it is the problem of hyperref, which will add a unsatishfied space around the items. The only way I found is to use the NoHyper to wrap the content.

Is there any other good solution to easily fix this? Especially adding the command to re-write the enviroment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array, longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{>{\centering}p{108pt}@{\hspace{7pt}}>{}p{375pt}}%
  \textcolor{lightgray}{factors} &
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, topsep=0em, parsep=0pt, before=\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\color{SlateGray!80}, after =\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
  \item a
  \item b
  \item c
  \item d
  \end{enumerate}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding vspace could easily fix the problem, however, if there are some words before items, the items content will overlap the lines.

Comment: Yes, but with `enumitem` you can define a new enumerate environment, say `tabenum`, with these characteristics, which you'll use only if there is nothing else in the cell.